# How to generate error with Nodemailer?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I want to test my Node.js + Express + Nodemailer app.

Can I generate an error?

```
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        console.log(error);

        res.contentType('json');
        res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.write(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: error }));
        res.end();
    }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);

        res.contentType('json');
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.write(JSON.stringify({ success: true, message: response.message }));
        res.end();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what type of error you are trying to receive.

Here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Enter an incorrect password in the mailOptions object for the account that will be sending the emails. This will produce an Authorization error of some sort.
2. Drop your internet connection before this code is executed. You can use node-inspector to insert a breakpoint in the server code to stop execution and disconnect from the network before resuming.

**To install node-inspector:**

`npm install -g node-inspector`

then run

`node-debug app.js`

Hope this helps!